# Can I have both svn 1.6 and 1.7 on Ubuntu 12.10 system

Tags: svn, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.10

On my Windows workstation was easy to use Tortoise 1.7 and command line 1.6 in NetBeans. Is it possible in Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you want to install both together?

Comment: Yes, I wish to use 1.7 with say RabbitCVS, and 1.6 with NetBeans.

Comment: Yes you can install! install and remane exes/ or install in diffrent directory ..

Comment: If so, which will be associated with `CLI: svn`

Comment: You have to create a softlink for which and as you desired. ..I think no other choice...I do it to keep diffrent versions of python

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what is the motivation for having the two versions installed?

Comment: You know about the backwards compatibility issues. Some old projects should remain in 1.6 repos.

Comment: You can use any Java-based SVN client (e.g. Netbeans), the most of them use SVNKit internally, and SVNKit transparently supports both working copy formats.

Comment: You can still upgrade all your working copies to 1.7 and interact with 1.6 repositories. See [Compatibility Concerns](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html#compatibility) section in the Subversion 1.7 release notes. I would simply standardise on 1.7 for the client and all working copies.

Answer (score 0):

As @Pedro Romano says, svn 1.7 client is fully compatible with svn 1.6 server. See [svn 1.7 compatibility](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html#compatibility)

You only need to do

```
$ svn updgrade working_dir1 working_dir2 ...
```

And work as always, the upgrade preserve local modifications. See [svn help upgrade](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/c/upgrade/)